# Get quantity of simple products in configurable products on list.phtml

Tags: magento2.3, category, product-list

I'm trying to get the qty of simple products in configurable products in the list page and it works with this code inside the product collection foreach:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');


foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):

$configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());

$_childrens = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);
 foreach ($_childrens as $child) {
  if ($StockState->getStockQty($child->getId(), $child->getStore()->getWebsiteId()) == 0) {
   echo "<span class='no-stock'>" . $child->getAttributeText('size') . "</span>";
  } else {
  echo "<span>" . $child->getAttributeText('size') . "</span>";
      }
}
endforeach;
```

But this is very SLOW! how can I get the qty without using the objectManager?

how need to extend the ProductList class? How?

thank you in advance for your support

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$childProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
                            foreach ($childProducts as $child) {
                                $blockObj = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Product');
                                if ($blockObj->getStock($child) == 0) {
                                    echo "<span class='no-stock'>" . $child->getAttributeText('size') . "</span>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "<span>" . $child->getAttributeText('size') . "</span>";
                                }
                                $priceFormatted = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency($child->getPrice(), true, false);
                            }
```

and custom block that extend template

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_stockInterface;
    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockInterface,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ){
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_stockInterface = $stockInterface;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getStockMessage($productId){
        $_product = $this->getProductById($productId);
        $_stock = $this->getStock($_product);
        if($_stock <= $this->getThresoldQty()){
            return __('Only %1 left', $_stock);
        }
        return '';
    }

    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    }

    public function getStock($_product)
    {
        return $this->_stockInterface->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    }

    public function getThresoldQty(){
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('cataloginventory/options/stock_threshold_qty', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    } 
}
```